# Group by doesnt give appropriate count in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

To my previous post, I taken all data in temp table like this

```
select * from #MyTempEmployeeTable
```

data:

```
version     count1  productname
------------------------------------------
10.0        2       Windows client Update
10.0        10      Windows client Update
10.0        486     Windows client Update
10.0.1      1       Windows client Update
10.0.1      2       Windows client Update
10.0.1      7       Windows client Update
10.0.1      9       Windows client Update
10.0.1      10      Windows client Update
10.0.1      56      Windows client Update
10.0.1      159     Windows client Update
10.0.1      233     Windows client Update
10.0.14     2       Windows client Update
10.0.14     3       Windows client Update
10.0.14     84      Windows client Update
10.0.14     265     Windows client Update
10.0.15     11      Windows client Update
10.0.15     29      Windows client Update
10.0.15     277     Windows client Update
10.0.15     8456    Windows client Update
10.0.18     1       Windows client Update
7.4.76      571     Windows client Update
7.5.7601    27      Windows client Update
7.6.76      1       Windows client Update
7.6.76      606     Windows client Update
7.6.7601    10      Windows client Update
7.6.7601    80      Windows client Update
7.6.7601    128     Windows client Update
7.6.7601    6491    Windows client Update
7.6.7601    51079   Windows client Update
7.8.9200    2       Windows client Update
7.8.9200    171     Windows client Update
7.9.9600    1       Windows client Update
7.9.9600    8       Windows client Update
7.9.9600    11      Windows client Update
7.9.9600    15      Windows client Update
7.9.9600    18      Windows client Update
7.9.9600    41      Windows client Update
7.9.9600    200     Windows client Update
7.9.9600    2026    Windows client Update
```

I'm writing the query below to get count with group by version but it isn't not returning the expected result.

```
select count(count1), version   
from #MyTempEmployeeTable 
group by version
```

Once I run this query I'm not getting appropriate data

```
(No column name)    version
------------------------------
3   10.0
8   10.0.1
4   10.0.14
4   10.0.15
1   10.0.18
1   7.4.76
1   7.5.7601
2   7.6.76
5   7.6.7601
2   7.8.9200
8   7.9.9600
```

Can you please help me out. for version 10.0 ideally I should be getting data as 496

[image]

Comment: share your appropriate data

Comment: You need SUM, not COUNT

Comment: i need for 10.0 version i should get total 2+10+486 = 498

Comment: god so stupid of me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you want `sum()` not count

```
select sum (count1),version   
from #MyTempEmployeeTable group by version
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `sum()`, not `count()`:

```
select sum(count1), version
from #MyTempEmployeeTable
group by version
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use SUM

```
select sum(count1),
  version 
from #MyTempEmployeeTable 
group by version
```

count is giving number of rows, sum is giving sum of values in the column.

and for version 10.0 you will get 498 (486+10+2), not 496 as in the question.